# Extract words from text using dplyr and stringr

Tags: r, regex, string, dplyr

I'm trying to find an effective way to extract words from an text column in a dataset. The approach I'm using is

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

Text = c("A little bird told me about the dog", "A pig in a poke", "As busy as a bee")
data = as.data.frame(Text)
keywords <- paste0(c("bird", "dog", "pig","wolf","cat", "bee", "turtle"), collapse = "|")
data %>% mutate(Word = str_extract(Text, keywords))
```

It's just an example but I have more than 2000 possible words to extract from each row. I don't know yet another approach to use, but the fact I will have a big regex will make things slow or doesn't matter the size of the regex? I think it will not appear more than one of these words in each row, but there is a way to make multiple columns automatically if more than one word appear in each row?

Comment: Do you need `v1 <- c("bird", "dog", "pig","wolf","cat", "bee", "turtle")
;map(v1,  ~ str_detect(data$Text, .x)) %>% set_names(v1) %>% as_tibble %>% bind_cols(data, .)`

Comment: A lot depends on whether you want to match whole words or just sequences of characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `str_extract_all` to return a `list`, convert the `list` elements to a named list or `tibble` and use `unnest_wider`

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  mutate(Words = str_extract_all(Text, keywords),
        Words = map(Words, ~ as.list(unique(.x)) %>% 
                              set_names(str_c('col', seq_along(.))))) %>%
  unnest_wider(Words)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  Text                                col1  col2 
#  <fct>                               <chr> <chr>
#1 A little bird told me about the dog bird  dog  
#2 A pig in a poke                     pig   <NA> 
#3 As busy as a bee                    bee   <NA>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. I just have a few doubts from a R newbie. Inside the unique() you passed an argument .x and there is no x variable, so it means to look for unique values in each row? When you used set_names() it creates new columns based on the number of unique words before you split the list with unnest_wider? What the dot (.) inside seq along means?

Comment: @Roland the `~ .x` is a shorter version of `function(x) x` for anonymous functions.  In tidyverse, the default value passed is `.` or `.x`.  YOu can also change it to regular functions with `map(Words, function(x) as.list(unique(x)) %>%`

Answer (score 1):

Try `intersect` with `keywords` as an array

```
data <- data.frame(Text = Text, Word = sapply(Text, function(v) intersect(unlist(strsplit(v,split = " ")),keywords),USE.NAMES = F))
```