# Concatenate string columns and order in alphabetical order

Tags: r

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
Text = c("A little bird told me about the dog", "A pig in a poke", "As busy as a bee")
data = as.data.frame(Text)
keywords <- paste0(c("bird", "dog", "pig","wolf","cat", "bee", "turtle"), collapse = "|")
data %>% 
  mutate(Words = str_extract_all(Text, keywords),
        Words = map(Words, ~ as.list(unique(.x)) %>% 
                              set_names(str_c('col', seq_along(.))))) %>%
  unnest_wider(Words)
```

This question is a continuation of this other question I asked (Question)[[Extract words from text using dplyr and stringr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58883580/extract-words-from-text-using-dplyr-and-stringr]).

Now I'm trying to find a way to concatenate the extracted columns in alphabetical order, but the only way that I find was making comparisons of type

```
col1 < col2 then col1 + col2
col1 > col2 then col2 + col1
```

Unfortunately this needs a lot of work for more than 3 columns. The output I desire is like this

```
col1 col2 col3 concatenated_string
dog  cat  bird bird + cat + dog
fish bird dog  bird + dog + fish
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `pmap_chr` and `sort`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(cs=pmap_chr(list(col1,col2,col3), ~paste(sort(c(...)), collapse = " + ")))

  col1 col2 col3                cs
1  dog  cat bird  bird + cat + dog
2 fish bird  dog bird + dog + fish
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `apply` you could do this...

```
data$concat <- apply(data[,-1], 1, function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse = "+"))

data
  Text                                col1  col2  concat    
1 A little bird told me about the dog bird  dog   bird+dog
2 A pig in a poke                     pig   NA    pig       
3 As busy as a bee                    bee   NA    bee
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using `unnest_wider`, use `unnest_longer` to put the data into long format. Then you can sort the words and paste them together

```r
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
Text = c("A little bird told me about the dog", "A pig in a poke", "As busy as a bee")
data = as.data.frame(Text)
keywords <- paste0(c("bird", "dog", "pig","wolf","cat", "bee", "turtle"), collapse = "|")
data %>% 
  mutate(Words = str_extract_all(Text, keywords),
         Words = map(Words, ~ as.list(unique(.x)) %>% 
                       set_names(str_c('col', seq_along(.))))) %>%
  unnest_longer(Words) %>% 
  group_by(Text) %>% 
  arrange(Words) %>% 
  summarise(result = paste(Words, collapse = " + "))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   Text                                result    
#>   <fct>                               <chr>     
#> 1 A little bird told me about the dog bird + dog
#> 2 A pig in a poke                     pig       
#> 3 As busy as a bee                    bee
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: is there any restriction with this set_names, it always give me an error and the column names look like ...1, ...2, ...3?

Comment: This is the error I get Error: `nm` must be `NULL` or a character vector the same length as `x`

Comment: Which function is giving the error? `traceback()` might help, as will running just part of the code